# How to allow customers to change qauntity for Pay Pal buttons

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox

If you go to https://developer.paypal.com/ and click get started, they walk you through in creating a Pay Pal button, which is pretty straight forward. On the page that allows you to customize your button, a light-box window pops up and allows you to adjust your settings for your new button.

But what is puzzling, is that there is no reference to for allowing the button to have an adjusted quantity option, just in case the customer wants to change that quantity value by the time they get to the Pay Pal gateway.

This is the sandbox button I created, which Pay Pal wants me to stick on my page...

```
<script src="paypal-button.js?merchant=myemailaddress" 
    data-button="buynow" 
    data-name="Payments To Me" 
    data-amount="25.00" 
    data-shipping="0" 
    data-tax="0" 
    data-callback="back to my site" 
    data-env="sandbox"
></script>
```

How do I adjust this to give customers the option to adjust the quantity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PayPal API accepts a "custom" field which you can set as anything you want and gets echoed back to your IPN. As far as I know, this is the only field you can use for custom data.

```
<script src="paypal-button.js?merchant=myemailaddress" 
  data-button="buynow" 
  data-name="Payments To Me" 
  data-amount= <?php echo($orderCount * 25) ?> + ".00" 
  data-shipping="0" 
  data-tax="0" 
  custom: {'orderCount':"<?=$orderCount ?>"}
  data-callback="back to my site" 
  data-env="sandbox">
</script>
```

The customer will be billed $25.00 * their ordercount and your notification message will include the custom field with your ordercount variable.

- the above example is if your website was powered by PHP. Use any conditional statements in the place of the `<? ?>` tag.

Comment: woooow! -  I learned something new!  I will test your initial demo.  on a side note, this script is being plugged into Smarty Template page. How would you adjust you PHP tags to be Smarty tags?  or is that not possible?  Thanks anwyay - this is a big help!

Comment: No problem, you can use Smarty tags or Javascript or even Angular instead of the PHP. It really depends on your application.